# Qt 5.7 Visual Studio - Modules grayed out

Tags: qt, module, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with the Qt5Package plug-in installed. When I'm making a new Qt application [image: application] and go to the modules tab, everything is grayed out[image: out] Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it? I built Qt 5.7.0 from source and I'm completely sure that I got all the modules on my computer.[image: modules] Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @krips89 No, I ended up using QT Creator :)